# Is resetting post data necessary with custom WP_CLI commands?

Tags: wp-cli, wp-reset-postdata

Is it strictly necessary to call `wp_reset_postdata();` in a WP CLI command? I am doing it out of habit but just wondered if the `$post` object needed to be reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little digging and found that the answer varies depending on your situation but for the most part no. If you are using the global $post variable outside a query then maybe.